# How to prevent radio buttons being selected by clicking their labels

Tags: html, radio-button, label

I have a group of radio buttons which each have their own labels. The label width is set to auto, which is what I want because the text length could increase in the future.

At the moment if I click the label it will select the corresponding radio button. As I understand it, this is default HTML behaviour. Is there any simple (by simple I mean preferably without using Javascript) way to suppress this default behaviour? So that I can select the radio button only by clicking the grey circle itself?

[image: Radio button wrapped in Label]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change this behavior, you first need to understand how to associate checkbox/radio elements with a `<label>`. If you understand that, then you can ensure that the `<input>` element isn't associated with a `<label>` element in order to prevent it from being selected.

There are two main ways:

- Wrap the `<input>` element with a `<label>` element in order to implicitly associate the elements:

```html
<p>Wrapping the input elements with a label will cause the input element to be selected when clicking on the label.</p>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="confirm" />Initial Decision
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="confirm" />Confirmation
</label>
```

- Associate the `<input>` element's `id` with the `<label>` element's `for` attribute to explicitly associate the elements:

```html
<p>If the input element's id matches the label element's for attribute, then clicking on a label element will select the corresponding input element:</p>

<input type="radio" id="initial" name="confirm" />
<label for="initial">Initial Decision</label>

<input type="radio" id="confirm" name="confirm" />
<label for="confirm">Confirmation</label>
```

Thus, you can effectively prevent the radio element from being selected when clicking on the `<label>` element by simply not associating the elements:

```html
<input type="radio" name="confirm" />
<label>Initial Decision</label>

<input type="radio" name="confirm" />
<label>Confirmation</label>
```

Comment: There are good reasons to associate a label and radio button --- most notably, accessibility. A more ideal solution would not rely upon severing the association.

Comment: @JohnnyTisdale - absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to prevent radio buttons being selected by clicking their labels?

Use this piece of code:

```css
.lbl-ungroup {overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.lbl-ungroup:after {content:" ";position:absolute; height:100%;width:100%;left:0;}
.lbl-ungroup label input[type=radio] {position:relative; z-index:1;}
```

```html
   
  
    <style>
        .lbl-ungroup {overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
        .lbl-ungroup:after {content:" ";position:absolute; height:100%;width:100%;left:0;}
        .lbl-ungroup label input[type=radio] {position:relative; z-index:1;}
</style>

    <div class="lbl-ungroup">
      
        <label><input type="radio" name="rbtgroup"> Male</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rbtgroup"> Female</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rbtgroup"> Other</label>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stop the event? Use these commands in JS code.

```
$('#some_id').on('click','label', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // your code below this line
});
```

This will prevent the event for selecting the radio button from bubbling up.